# Is endless fire possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Is it thermodynamically possible to have endless fire, given the case that we had an equally endless supply of fuel for this fire?

Comment: Also an endless supply of oxidant, and endless room for the reaction products (which are forever flowing away from the fire, as not to asphyxiate it)... why not? Any particular motivations for your question?

Comment: Related: http://www.snopes.com/college/exam/hell.asp

Comment: Thank you very much! And no, I do not have any particular motivations  to ask this, just mere curiosity.

Comment: -1. It is not clear to me what your difficulty is, and what this has got to do with thermodynamics and entropy. As stafusa asks, What is your motivation? Why do you think the answer might be other than the obvious Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often realised: an acetylene torch is a fine example.

Thermodynamics may be known for various depressing conclusions about how closed systems will eventually run down and end up in a maximum entropy equilibrium state. But if the system is open, then other steady states are possible. In this case, if fuel and oxygen are supplied and waste gas and heat removed, we can have a steady state where the reaction releases energy continuously and will do so indefinitely.

[Steady states require some conditions](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100841a011), basically that they are attractive fixed points in state space. An initial state that is not quite there at ignition will converge to it over time, and if there is a disturbance it will be dampened out. If things are linear enough [entropy production is minimal](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Minimum_entropy_production_principle). It is possible for chemical reactions (including flames) to oscillate if things get nonlinear.